# Order of bare webroot folder blog expression

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases, adjective-order

I used such a phrase in my tutorial blog:
`bare webroot folder blog`. It is quite long but I don't know if the order of words is proper.

The sense of use this phrase is that somebody creates such a folder.

I explain what are these words:

- bare - something like empty
- webroot - type of folder
- folder - the directory in a computer
- blog - name of the folder

I would express it in the sentence like this:
`Bare folder of the name "blog" that is a webroot folder.` but I am looking for a short expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I've never seen the word "bare" used to refer to an empty folder. I'd rather stick to simply calling it "empty".

Second, "blog" should really be either in quotes or - as is commonly the case in technical writing - distinguished from the surrounding text by `fixed-width typeface`. Otherwise the phrase is a little confusing - are you asking the reader to create a blog about bare webroot folders?

If you really need a short phrase, it'd probably go something like this:

> Then, create an empty webroot folder `blog`...

although I'd rephrase it as

> Then, create an empty webroot folder **named** `blog`...

just to make the sentence clearer.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to put *blog* in a different typeface than any other word. It's a legitimate [word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blog) that can be used as both a noun and verb—and context determines its use, just as it does with other words.

Comment: @JasonBassford except in this context it's not used in its actual meaning, but just as a name of the folder. Without a distinct typeface or quotes ("Create an empty webroot folder blog") the object of the sentence appears to be *blog*, and the sentence instructs the reader to create a blog, with *folder* serving as a a sort-of noun adjunct.

Comment: You would say, "Refer to the man (named) John Smith." You would not say, "Refer to the man (named) `John Smith`."

Comment: @JasonBassford there's no ambiguity in your sentence since "John Smith" is a proper noun (and also distinguished by capital letters). Cf. "Refer to the box labeled documents" / "Refer to the box labeled 'documents'" - the first sentence makes "box labeled" describe "documents", the other makes "labeled 'documents'" describe "box".